# Como llamar distintas variables en un for

Tags: c#

estoy intentando implementar un for que llame a unas variables las cuales compraten el mismo nombre pero terminan con distinto numero,para poder imprementar un metodoy cuando se cumpla el ciclo se incremente para que el metodo llame a una variable distinta.

```
int num1;
int num2;
int num3;


    for (int i = 1; i<3; i++)
        {
            metodo(num + i);
        }
```

Se que es posible agregando el $ si mal no me acuerdo pero no recuerdo como implementarlo

Gracias!

Comment: System.Reflection.FieldInfo te ofrece lo que buscas. Pero para tu caso presentado es siempre mejor usar array para hacer desde el for y acceder a las variables.

Answer (score 0):

Tal como está tu planteamiento, no es posible.

Una forma de manejarlo es utilizando un arreglo de la siguiente manera:

```
    //Declaracion del arreglo
    int[] num = new int[3];

    // Se asume que los valores del arreglo son inicializados en alguna parte
    // por ejemplo
    num[0] = 3;
    num[1] = 8;
    num[2] = 9;


    for (int i = 0; i<3; i++)
    { 
        metodo(num[i]);
    }
```

Lo que me viene a la mente que involucra un `$` es la [interpolación de string](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/string-interpolation), pero eso se utiliza para facilitar la composición de texto y no los nombres de variables.

**Actualización (String interpolation)**

Con base en tu comentario, a continuación un ejemplo de uso para `String interpolation`:

Supongamos que tienes las variables:

```
string color = "azul";
int cantidad = 5;
```

y tienes que construir un mensaje que incluya el contenido de esas variables.

Puedes utilizar la siguiente sintaxis (y es la que supongo que estás buscando):

```
string mensaje = $"Se encontraron {cantidad} elementos de color {color}";
```

o puedes utilizar `string.Format` de la siguiente manera (la incluyo para contrastar las diferencias):

```
string mensaje = string.Format("Se encontraron {0} elementos de color {1}", cantidad, color);
```

Ambas producen el mismo resultado, sin embargo la primera es más fácil de escribir y de leer.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta,el tema es que en realidad lo que manejo serian controladores de un winform(TextBox),se que haciendo $"codigo" es lo mismo que string.format(),quizas recuerdo mal ,pero creo que habia otra forma de implementar el $ para concatenar nombres de variables

Comment: @EmilianoScolaro acabo de editar mi respuesta para inluir un ejemplo basado en tu comentario.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que precisas es pasar todos o parte de los controles TextBox a un método puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
foreach(Control myControl in this.Controls)
{
    if (myControl.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
    {
         Metodo((TextBox)myControl);
    }    
}
```

Recuerda que cada control además de su propiedad Name que lo identifica dispone de una propiedad Tag que podemos usar para guardar información adicional. Por ejemplo, si tengo 4 controles TextBox pero 2 son pongamos de cantidades de ingreso y los otros dos son de gastos. Se podría usar la propiedad Tag con el valor GASTO en los de gastos e INGRESO en los de ingresos. De esta forma nuestra rutina podría quedar así:

```
// recorre los controles existente en el contenedor (en este caso el form)
foreach(Control myControl in this.Controls)
{
    // Si el control es un TextBox actuamos
    if (myControl.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
    {
         if (myControl.Tag == "INGRESO")     // Si es un Ingreso lo paso al método 1
            Metodo_1_Ingresos((TextBox)myControl);
         else if (myControl.Tag == "GASTO")  // Si es un Gasto lo paso al método 2
            Metodo_2Gastos((TextBox)myControl);
    }    
}
```

Y si tu método no precisa de recibir el control entero (porque no vaya a  hacer ninguna acción sobre el mismo) sino que sólo necesitas el contenido, pues le pasas la propiedad Text del mismo:

```
// Si sólo se precisa pasar el contenido del control
Metodo( ((TextBox)myControl).Text );
```